# "Из явных недостатков - это отсутствие кнопок снизу." Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые, подлежащее

> Из явных недостатков - это отсутствие кнопок снизу.

Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Один) из явных недостатков — это отсутствие кнопок снизу.**

Слово ***один*** пропущено. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что подлежащее выражено словосочетанием  ***из явных недостатков*** с упрощенной грамматикой. ***Это*** — связка, ***отсутствие*** — сказуемое (составное именное, с пропущенной связкой *есть*).

Comment: Спасибо. Сказуемое здесь "отсутствие кнопок снизу" или только "отсутствие"?

Comment: Только "отсутствие", остальные слова распространяют сказуемое.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, в данном случае стоит говорить об эллипсисе, т. е. пропуске части подлежащего: «**[Один/главный]** из явных недостатков — это отсутствие кнопок снизу».

Таким образом, подлежащее здесь представлено частично, лишь фрагментом «из недостатков». Сказуемое — *отсутствие*.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение не совсем корректно. При том, что это *неполное* предложение, оно содержит *лишний*, отождествляющий две его части элемент **это**, который не согласован с предшествующей частью, - это не исправляется постановкой чего-либо опущенного на место тире. Полное предложение могло быть таким (*безличный* вариант):

> Из явных недостатков можно отметить отсутствие кнопок снизу.

Допустимым выглядит неполный вариант без **это**:

> Из явных недостатков - отсутствие кнопок снизу.

Здесь можно трактовать тире как элемент замещения опущенных слов полного предложения. Такое неполное предложение было бы уместным при наличии предшествующего контекста, проясняющего смысл пропущенного, например, перед ним могло быть такое вступление:

> Можно отметить целый ряд упущений.

Comment: "Не совсем корректно"? Приведенное в вопросе предложение нужно признать неграмотным.